# Error creating ext4 file system

Tags: hard-disk, cubieboard

Recently I purchased a Cubietruck Cubieboard 3, and I'm trying to copy Lubuntu server from the builtin NAND memory to a hard disk.

I can create a partition successfully, but when I go to format the partition with ext4, using `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1`, I get a bunch of errors, which all look the same:

```
Writing inode tables: done
Creating Journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information:
[  815.XXXXXX] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  815.XXXXXX] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000000
[  815.XXXXXX] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  815.XXXXXX] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:00:00:08:1c/00:00:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
[  815.XXXXXX]          res 41/40:00:02:08:1c/00:00:00:00/60 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[  815.XXXXXX] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  815.XXXXXX] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[...] above 7 lines repeated 5x, each with a 6 second time difference
[  845.XXXXXX] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1837058
```

I don't think it is the drive, because it is new, and I can also format it on Elementary (Ubuntu). If I format it from Elementary, I can then not mount it on my Cubieboard.

Comment: `Emask 0x409 (media error)` seems to be a drive problem.  If you have direct access to the drive you should run DFT on it (can be found on UBCD - http://ultimatebootcd.com).  If it passes a full advanced test then try disabling the drive cache (as dumb as that sounds).

Comment: Disabling the drive cash stopped the errors! Thanks!

Comment: I guess I'll go and put that as an answer so people see it in the future as such.  Glad it helped.

Comment: That's a disk driver or hardware error. Before you go on using that disk, I recommend that you find out exactly what is causing the error. Otherwise you risk hiding the symptoms but not getting rid of the actual bug and eventually lose data to the bug.

Comment: Please post the output itself and not a picture next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the drive cache and try re-formatting again.  The system is getting ahead of the hardware.